# Jenkins no deja clonar en una carpeta especifica

Tags: github, jenkins

estoy tratando de correr un pipeline donde hace clone de un repositorio en github a través de ssh pero me da este error en la consola de jenkins.

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: java.io.IOException: Creating directories for /home/ubuntu/projects/go/.git failed
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$4.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:1458)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1223)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1301)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:125)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:93)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Creating directories for /home/ubuntu/projects/go/.git failed
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.FileUtils.mkdirs(FileUtils.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.FileRepository.create(FileRepository.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository.create(Repository.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.JGitAPIImpl$4.execute(JGitAPIImpl.java:1400)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Sin tener muchos detalles, parece una falla de permisos o algo parecido. Ciertamente no es un problema de git _per se_ sino que por alguna razón no puede crear el directorio que está indicando.

Comment: Eso parece, pero no se como dar permisos ya que no se como agregar un sudo en el git clone teniendo en cuenta que es con SSH.

Comment: Ok.... creo que vas a tener que explicar con mas detalles los usuarios involucrados (los que ejecutan los procesos) y los permisos que tienen los directorios involucrados para entender mas del contexto.

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvi haciendo lo siguiente.

```
$sudo visudo
## Now add the below lines in your sudoers file :
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

$service jenkins start
```